# Is there a new way to remove sites from Google search results?

Tags: google-search

A while ago I got fed up with continuously finding [w3schools](http://w3fools.com) in my search results when I wanted detailed, technically correct information.

To fix this without having to continuously append `-site:w3schools.com` to my search queries, I used Google's [Manage Blocked Sites](https://www.google.com/reviews/t) page.

For a while this worked perfectly, no more results from unwanted sites. Recently, however, I've been seeing w3schools litter my search results.

> Is there a *new* way to remove a site from Google search results?
>   -or-
>   Is this just a bug that I should report?

Comment: This would be good to know for that other bugbear of mine, experts-exchange.com...

Comment: While I understand the similarity of the questions, I do not believe them to be duplicates. I suppose the title of this one should/could be changed, as it probably caused confusion to people who must not have actually read the body of the question.

Comment: I am having this issue too. There is no indication from Google that they removed the feature, it's still in their help pages here: http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386 You can do what I did and send feedback/bug report on the article by rating it at the bottom.

Comment: @Al Everett, I understand you were trying to be helpful, but the statement itself was flawed. Not having the right answers isn't the appropriate reason to ask a new question. The questions themselves are inherently different. If the answers on the other questions weren't working for me, I would have opened a bounty on the existing questions.

Comment: @zzzzBov: What are you talking about?

Comment: @AlEverett, I'm referencing the edit you had made to my question starting with "I have seen 'Is there a way to remove...".

Comment: @zzzzbov: Ah. I'd done that to help reinforce that this wasn't a duplicate question. Basically I paraphrased what you said in comments on November 26.

Comment: I arrived at this answer because I got tired of seeing w3schools in my search results. So I googled "remove website from search results". I love the internet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known bug that showed up past year.
Google is aware of it as you can read [on google groups](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/websearch/vUVLiOKUXwU/BhSXNrjVQnsJ):

> We're aware that this is an issue and I'll post an update as soon as I have one.  In the meantime, thanks for your patience.

The only solution you have for now is a browser script/extension.

Comment: If you are looking for an extension, Google's extension "Personal Blocklist" no longer works as of 2018-10.

Comment: @BrianC.:  uBlacklist [that you suggested](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121506/111486) still works.

Answer (score 15):

For the Chrome browser, there is an extension for this: [Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef). I use it at expert-exchange.com etc.
You can read about it [here](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-chrome-extension-block-sites-from.html).

Comment: A great recommendation, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: As of 2015-07-30, this extension no longer functions. It looks like Google stopped updating it almost a year ago, and it stopped working in a subsequent version of Chrome.

Comment: As of 2018-10-18 it is still not working.

Answer (score 6):

Now that Google's extension "Personal Block List" is broken you'll need a different extension.

The Chrome extension [uBlacklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe) works to block sites from Google Search results.

Comment: As of 2020-12 uBlacklist still works.

Answer (score 5):

[Google has discontinued support for their "Manage Blocked Sites" feature](https://www.google.com/reviews/t), and explicitly recommends using the [Chrome extension for blocking sites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef).

> Manage Blocked Sites (DISCONTINUED) Dear users, We have discontinued offering the blocked sites feature for now. We continue to offer the Chrome extension for blocking sites, and will reconsider features for blocking unwanted search results in the future

Comment: The extension recommend in this answer has not worked for years.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to [chrome://settings/searchEngines](http://chrome://settings/searchEngines) you can set your personal search engine and prefix every search you enter in the address field with `-site:w3schools.com`:

[image: Set personal search engine in chrome]

I added the following, which prefixes all my address field searches to exclude results from `w3schools.com`:

`Google`

`google.com`

`{google:baseURL}search?q=-site:w3schools.com %s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`

Comment: This works but it adds `-site:w3schools.com` to the search box which is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Addon for Firefox: [Hide Unwanted Results of Google Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/?src=api)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is if Google's blocking algorithm has a bug or they've changed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `-w3schools` keyword to your search query if you only want to remove it for certain queries.

Comment: "To fix this without having to continuously append -site:w3schools.com to my search queries, I used Google's Manage Blocked Sites page."

Comment: That is specifically what OP doesn't want to do though.

Answer (score -1):

This personal block list extension is a life saver. All of this annoying search results which google provides hitting the top list is extremely aggravating.

Like such basic common articles news, new york times wants me to pay when I can get the same material (hundreds of them) for free.

Also search results containing massive adware's and dumb information

Comment: Welcome to [webapp.se]! This looks like it's a reply to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35787/136642) rather than an answer on its own.