# How to block sites with Google News?

Tags: google-news

I'm fed up with the sensationalized stories from http://www.dailymail.co.uk and would like it **not** to appear in my news search results. I found [a way to eliminate it](http://support.google.com/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1146405) from the news.google.com aggregation when I'm logged into my Google account.

However, if I search for topics in the News section, that site shows up in the results. I realize I can do a `-site:dailymail.co.uk`, but I tried [adding it to blocked sites in general search preferences (requires login to Google)](https://www.google.com/reviews/t?hl=en), but that didn't work.

Here's a [related question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35786/19350) that implies blocking sites doesn't always work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but did you clear your cookies/cache recently?

Comment: @Hydra your comment led me to test further. It seems that it's a problem with [Google multiple sign-in](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1721977). If I'm signed into more than one account, even though I use the account which has blocked dailymail.co.uk for the news search, the search ignores that setting. The solution is to sign out of all accounts and **only** sign into the the account which has blocked the site.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but I've had the same problem... Google is really annoyingly pushing up Mail and Express, I wonder why... Anyways, I found out that [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=news&kp=1&t=h_&ia=news&iar=news)'s newsfeed is not so much worse. Seems to come with a bit of delay, but on political topics is so much better without all the clickbait nonsense.

Answer (score -2):

- First unsubscribe from the website you registered
- Sign in gmail
- Go to google.co.in/preferences
- Click Block unwanted sites
  Try this..

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear in my question, but I already tried this. The site is "manually blocked" in that list, but News still shows its articles in the feed.