# How to filter sources in news.google.com?

Tags: google-news

I would like to define a blacklist for news sources. I can not find the configuration option. Does it exist? Or can I use some kind of proxy to achieve my aim?

Comment: This question has [already been](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/how-to-block-sites-with-google-news) asked.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do (just within Google News) is reduce a news source to "rarely", but you won't be able to get rid of it altogether.

On Google News, click the <kbd>Personalize</kbd> button.

There, you'll find a number of sliders to change the frequency of news from certain *Topics*. Below that is a place to "Adjust Sources".

In the text box, type the name of the source you want to not see. Auto-complete should suggest it in short order. Choose the source, and then move the slider left as far as it will go ("Rarely").

Click <kbd>Save</kbd>. Depending on how much news you consume and on what topics, you should now see that news source hardly or not at all.